# ideal in the smaller ring needs not to be ideal in the larger ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A\subset B$ be two commutative rings, let $I\subset A$ be an ideal of $A$, does $I$ is always an ideal of the larger ring?

I know that if $I$ is prime in $A$ it needs not to be prime in $B$ for example prime ideal $(5)$ in $\Bbb{Z}$ needs not to prime in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ as it factor in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ to $(1+2i)(1-2i)$.

I was wondering is the ideal in $A$ always ideal in $B$? (I think it's not, as image of the ideal in general not an ideal)?

Comment: $2\Bbb Z$ is an ideal in $\Bbb Z$ but not in $\Bbb Q.$

Comment: Oh thank you for those example, I see now.

Comment: You already had one: $(5)$ in $\Bbb Z$ means $5\Bbb Z$ whereas in $\Bbb Z[i]$ it means $5\Bbb Z[i].$ So $5\Bbb Z$ is an ideal in $\Bbb Z$ but not in $\Bbb Z[i].$

Comment: @yili $0$ is a counterexample to your claim and I don't understand your argument.

Comment: @Anne Bauval , it's not a arguement, I simply want to convey some feeling (it's reasonable to find there almost no example of ideal in smaller ring being ideal in the larger ring, as image of ideal under the surjective ring homomorphism is agian ideal and inclusion is very opposite to the surjection.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. The set $\{2n: n\in \Bbb Z\}$ is an ideal in $\Bbb Z$ but it isn't in $\Bbb R$.

Thinking on commutative rings: note that one the conditions for $I$ to be an ideal is that $xI\subseteq I$ for every $x$ in the ring. If you add elements into the ring, the condition can fail.